# Determine whether a set of 4, 2x2 matrices form a base for M2.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am  having a hard time solving this question:

Let $A,B,C,D,E$ be  $2\times2$ matrices above R field.

### If $\{\,AE,BE,CE,DE\,\}$ linearly independent then $E$ must be an invertible matrix.

it feels like a proof and it concerns bases and dimensions which is our current subject.

Thanks alot
Tom

Comment: Are you actually having a hard time understanding the question? or are you just having a hard time solving it?

Comment: hard time solving it would be more suitable.. I know that for the same group whilst E must be singular, that's obviously not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_2(\mathbb R)$ is four-dimensional. So, if $AE,BE,CE,DE$ are linearly independent, they must span $M_2(\mathbb R)$. Therefore, there exist scalars $a,b,c,d$ such that $aAE+bBE+cCE+dDE=I$, meaning that $E^{-1}=aA+bB+cC+dD$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint. It may be slightly easier to work with the contrapositive here, which is the statement that:

If $E$ is a singular matrix, then the set $S=\{AE,BE,CE,DE\}$ is linearly dependent.

To prove this, consider the fact that a set of $4$ matrices over a $4$ dimensional space will be a linearly independent set if and only if it is also a spanning set. So it suffices to prove that $S$ does not span the space of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ matrices. Since $E$ is singular by assumption, what can we say about its kernel? What can we then say about the kernel of
$$c_1AE + c_2BE + c_3CE + c_4DE,$$
for arbitrary scalars $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$? Why does this imply that $S$ is not a spanning set?

Comment: I hope to the right terms, or at least as close as is can. I am not studying in English so it makes it a little harder to get used to it all at once.

Comment: anyhow, with my understanding it means that for a singular matrix, such as E, it's kernel would be infinite?, and so does the the sum of the rest?, which leads us to a set of linearly dependent vectors?

Answer (score 2):

If $A,B,C,D$ are linearly dependent, then (trivially) $AE,BE,CE,DE$ are linearly dependent, so we may assume $A,B,C,D$ linearly independent. The vector space $M_2$ of $2\times2$ matrices has dimension 4, so this makes $A,B,C,D$ a basis for $M_2$, a fortiori, a spanning set for $M_2$.

Now assume $E$ is singular. This implies there's a $2\times2$ matrix $F\ne0$ such that $FE=0$. Since $A,B,C,D$ is a spanning set for $M_2$, there are scalars $r,s,t,u$, not all zero, such that $rA+sB+tC+uD=F$. Then $$r(AE)+s(BE)+t(CE)+u(DE)=(rA+sB+tC+uD)E=FE=0$$ so $AE,BE,CE,DE$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gerry!, would you mind clarifying the sentence: Now assume E is singular. This implies there's a 2×2 matrix F≠0 such that FE=0. If I get it right, it derives from the reason that by elimination you can get as far as receiving a row/column of 0's?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to make the connection.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful!

Comment: If you feel that one of the answers posted here has answered your question, I would encourage you to click in the check mark next to it, to "accept" it.